# Usage of "since" and "for" in the present perfect and simple past tense

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, perfect-aspect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

1. Can we use *since* and *for* with past tense?
2. If we can use them, then what is difference between:

> - I have learnt English for 3 months
> - I learnt English for 3 months

Comment: It would usually be: *"I have been learning English for three months"*, or *"I have been learning English since September"* (unless you now know English, and so are no longer learning it).

Comment: are you saying that we should not use since and for with present perfect tense.

Comment: related [Is it correct to use the past simple with 'Since'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54635/is-it-correct-to-use-the-past-simple-with-since) and [“Has changed since March 1” vs “Changed on March 1”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208622/has-changed-since-march-1-vs-changed-on-march-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper usage of "since" and "from" with regard to duration of time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/proper-usage-of-since-and-from-with-regard-to-duration-of-time) Also read this short [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95065/44619) by @BarrieEngland  and this question: [**When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/when-is-the-present-perfect-tense-used-instead-of-the-past-tense)

Comment: Finally this more detailed [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66898/44619) by Barrie England to the question: *Is there any difference between Present Perfect and Present Perfect Continuous?* This is what Peter Shor in the comments was referring to.

Comment: I'm saying that ***for your specific example*** of *"to learn English",* you should use the present perfect continuous. *"I have learnt English since September"* and *"I learnt English since September"* are perfectly good uses of the present perfect tense and the past tense with *"since"*, but they both imply that you now know English, which I assume isn't what you wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "for" for a period of time beginning with the action until the present, and since for a moment of time from when the action first took place, e.g., I have lived here for three months or I have lived here since September.

Comment: that you mean we should not use since and for with sentence in simple past tense

Comment: You can use for with the past. "I lived there for three months" meands that I do not live there now. "From would be better than since to express the same where appropriate.

Comment: so i lived there for three months & i have lived there for three months. both are correct and gives same meaning , am i right @Martin

Comment: The meaning with the present perfect is that you still live there and with the simple past that you have since stopped living there.

Comment: as i know(i learnt like this), to say still live there i use 
present perfect continuous tense (I have been living there for three months)

Comment: It would be incorrect to say, "I have been living here for all my life" and better to sat "I have lived here for all my life"

Comment: *I've lived here all my life* is also fine

Comment: then it's wrong to say, i have been here for three months .when we want to say still i am staying there. am i right

Comment: The use of the present perfect continuous implies a te,porary state ad the present perfect simple more of a permanent state.